# Changes to Hot Network Questions

Tags: discussion, hnq-removal

There are several changes, one that jumps out to me as potentially important for Pets.se is this one.

> Moderators have the ability to remove questions from the HNQ List.
>   There are times when the hotness formula selects a question that a site would rather not have featured. Up until now, the only recourse that was available was to close the question (which may be appropriate anyway but isn't ideal when done purely to manage traffic), or to do nothing. We're putting the power in the hands of our moderators to remove questions that don't set a good example for their sites. I recommend each site have a meta discussion with guidance for moderators about when - if ever - a question should be removed. Source [Updating the Hot Network Questions List - now with a bit more network and a little less “hotness”!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325060/217279)

We get on the Hot Network Questions list fairly often and normally it is a good thing.  Occasionally it is questionable.  Most of you may recall a recent example that I am not going to name, it does not need any more attention.

I don't think we need to make any decisions now, but if in the future there is a question that the community would prefer not remain on the Hot Network Questions list; start a meta discussion about it.

Put one **Remove** from Hot Network Questions list answer

And one **Keep** on the Hot Network Questions list answer

If/when the **Remove** has 5 votes more then the **Keep** answer, we can consider that as consensus to remove from Hot Network Questions list.

In any case Hot Network Questions, will not stay on the list for more than 3 days.

> Questions will age out of the list after being on it for 72 hours.

- Mods can only select the "remove from hot network questions" button while the question is on the list.  The HNQ list is updated every 15 minutes, and questions near the bottom may cycle on and off with updates.

Comment: Appreciate the initiative, but I'm a little bit confused about the goal of this meta post. Is it just an announcement to handle future HNQ, or also to discuss in general what kind of topic that might need more attention for HNQ prevention (because I currently have one in mind)? :)

Comment: @AndrewT. I interpreted it as an announcement of how this feature will/should be used on this site.

Comment: @AndrewT., JAD's assement is correct.  Is the question you have in mind currently on the HNQ list?  If so open a meta post about it.  I was not aware that we currently have any HNQ.

Comment: @JamesJenkins thanks for the clarification. Nah.. it was about a specific HNQ in the past (which maybe is the one you stated that "I am not going to name"), because the topic revolving around *that*, while it might be entertaining to some, it might also give a wrong/bad impression of this site and SE network overall.

Comment: @AndrewT. We are probably talking about the same post.  I have never seen an old question get back on list after weeks/months.  So I don't think we need to worry about old stuff.  Just looking forward.  And probably only if it it actually hits the HNQ list, which normally happens in the first hours of being posted.

Answer (score 4):

Good idea for a way to discuss these decisions. I have one suggestion.

These kinds of discussions could probably use a tag like [hnq-removal](/questions/tagged/hnq-removal). The tag description could then link to this question for guidelines on how to use it. It would also allow moderators to set up notifications when these kinds of discussions are posted. This is useful, because only moderators can act on the decision made here.