# HNQ - "How can I stop my kitten from growing?"

Tags: discussion, hnq-removal

Per [Changes to Hot Network Questions](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2274/13) starting the discussion.  There have been mixed thoughts if this question is appropriate.

Should the question [How can I stop my kitten from growing?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/25436/13) be removed from HNG

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Remove

Vote to remove from HNQ

Comment: With a vote of 9 to 1 I removed the question from the HNQ

Answer (score -3):

### Keep

Vote to keep on the HNQ